# Regex - extract info from a String in Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have a problem in applying a regex in my Java code.
My text string is like this (String myString)

```
        name: Abc Def;
        blah: 1 2 3;
        second name: Ghi;
```

I need to extract the name information (**Abc Def**). Name can contain a string of 1+ words. All the properties (name, blah, second name) are spaced with some whitespaces at the beginning

The code I'm trying to use is

```
String patternStr = "\\s{2,}name:\\s([\\w ]*\\w+);";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(patternStr).matcher(myString);
if (matcher.matches()) 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

My regex seems working fine with [online tools](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) (regex: \s{2,}name:\s([\w ]*\w+);) but when I port it to java code it simply doesn't work. Any idea of what I'm missing?

Thanks a lot

---

Edit:
If I use matcher.find() it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that `.match( )` tries to match the whole input line. So either you can add a .+ at the end of the pattern to eat the rest of the line or use `.contains( )`.
(with `.match( )` the `^` and `$` at the start and end of the pattern are implicit)

Note that you need to provide a flag when you need to match against multi-line input: `.compile(patternStr, Perl5Compiler.MULTILINE_MASK)`

Answer (score 5):

Here ya go:

```
^\s*name:\s*([^;]+);
```

- Start at the beginning of the line.
- Eat as much whitespace as there is.
- Find "name:"
- Eat as much whitespace as there is.
- Capture anything before the next semicolon
- Make sure there's a semicolon

Comment: Thanks for the regex improvement but I think that the problem is when I call matcher.matches(). If I use matcher.find() it works fine.